# Dereferencing values from an array to declared variables in one line

Tags: perl, reference, dereference

To retrieve arguments from a function call I usually do

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foo([1,2],[3,4]);

sub foo{
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    ...
}
```

In the example, $x and $y are now references to an array each. If I want to use the variables inside these arrays easily I dereference them first.

```
...
my ($x1, $x2) = @{$x}[0,1];
# ...same for $y
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to dereference the arguments in @_ (or, indeed, any other array) and return them to a list of declared variables in just one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foo ( [1,2], [3,4] );

sub foo {

    my ( $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2 ) = map @$_, @_;

    ...
}
```

The `map` takes `@_` and dereferences each of its elements into an array with the `@$_` operation.

One could also use [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Gen)'s `deref` or `d` functions to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

That's why I have `unroll`:

```
sub unroll (@) { 
    return map { ref() eq 'ARRAY' ? @$_ : ref() eq 'HASH' ? %$_ : $_ } @_;
}
```

So that I can go like this:

```
my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = unroll @_;
```

(or)

```
my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = &unroll;
```

A lot prettier than

```
map { @$_ } @_[0, 1]
```

and the like. Plus, it's a bit more robust.

Comment: What's with the `@{[ ... ]}`, and what's with using `@_[0,1]` in some places and `@_` in others. False dichotomy!

Comment: As for robustness, `map @$_, @_` works with all arrays, where `unroll` does not. Furthermore, `map @$_, @_` detects more bad inputs than `unroll` does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get exactly what you want, but is this ok :

```
foo([1,2],[3,4]);
sub foo{
    my ($x1,$x2) = @{$_[0]}[0,1];
    say "x1=$x1 , x2=$x2";
}
```

**output:**

```
x1=1 , x2=2
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking about. He wants to fetch `($x1, $x2, $y1, $y2)` in one line.

Comment: I guess I could fetch them all by using `my ($x1,$x2,$y1,$y2) = (@{$_[0]}[0,1], @{$_[1]}[0,1]);`. So maybe I am simply wondering if there is a quick way to flatten an array of arrays :/